# p4a Could not find `android` or `sdkmanager` binaries in Android SDK. Exiting

Tags: android, sdk, kivy

I spend hours struggling on this issue and I feel dumb as f***. I followed [this doc](http://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart/#installation), installed everything I needed until the effective building step:

```
p4a apk --debug --private $HOME/Documents/Code/Python/app_kivy/identifier/main.py --package=org.example.myapp --name "My application" --version 0.1 --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python2,kivy
[INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs: armeabi
[INFO]:    Found Android API target in $ANDROIDAPI
[ERROR]:   Could not find `android` or `sdkmanager` binaries in Android SDK. Exiting.
```

Here is the end of my .bashrc

```
# Adjust the paths!
export ANDROIDSDK="$HOME/Android/Sdk/"
export ANDROIDNDK="$HOME/Apps/android-ndk-r16b/"
export ANDROIDAPI="19"  # Minimum API version your application require
export ANDROIDNDKVER="r16b"  # Version of the NDK you installed
```

I tried several paths variants, tried both the full Android Studio and the ‘just the command line tools’ methods of the doc, nothing. NB **android** and **sdkmanager** are installed in different folders (resp. tools and tools/bin). I am pretty sure that I am missing something in the .bashrc but what am I missing?

Thanks in advance for any insight

Answer (score 1):

This p4a error message is less specific than it implies. `$ANDROIDSDK` need not even be a valid path to produce this error.  That in mind, you should first check that it has even been exported properly by running the command `echo $ANDROIDSDK`.  If you don't see the expected path printed out, you'll need to run your .bashrc script again the way you normally would.

If you do see the expected path, then the most likely problem is that the contents of `$HOME/Android/Sdk/` aren't what p4a was expecting.  For that I unfortunately can't offer a suggestion of what might be wrong without knowing what the contents are.